# Events manager - child theme not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make changes to plugins/events-manager/templates/forms/event/bookings.php via my child theme. When I make changes to the file directly in the plugin, it works well, but I know the way to go is to make changes at the child theme level so this is what i have done:

I added the edited bookings.php to twentytwelve-child/plugins/events-manager/templates/forms/event/bookings.php but for some reasons the changes are not applied.

I have also tried to add the edited bookings.php to twentytwelve-child/events-manager/templates/forms/event/bookings.php but it is not working either.

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure this out (screenshots below). FYI - I am not a developer, so please try not to be too technical in your answers.

Many thanks,
Yvan

[image: Child theme directories]

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if developers could simply override a specific file within a plugin from within their theme, but I'm pretty sure WP doesn't work that way (At least not for overriding plugins. Theme files? Yes. Plugins? No).

If the plugin developer was nice they will have given you some override capabilities like using [action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), or including their function as static within a class.

From the looks of [the events-manager plugin file](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/events-manager/tags/5.6.1/templates/forms/event/bookings.php) there are three such action hooks available:

```
do_action('em_events_admin_bookings_header', $EM_Event);
do_action('em_event_edit_ticket_td', $EM_Ticket);
do_action('em_events_admin_bookings_footer', $EM_Event);
```

You will either need to hook into these actions to make your adjustments (highly recommended), or duplicate the plugin, rename it, and edit it manually (which means you will need to duplicate these edits every time you upgrade... YUCK!)

EDIT after further researching the events-manager plugin:

While WP doesn't provide this template override functionality, it looks like the plugin does. However after some digging in the documentation I noticed that this functionality doesn't specify weather it supports child themes. Try placing the template override within twentytwelve instead of twentytwelve-child. If that works, then maybe you could move that folder back into twentytwelve-child and create a [symlink](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal) within twentytwelve to the real folder in twentytwelve-child (sort of tricking the plugin). Doing it this way means you have to recreate the symlink each time you update twentytwelve, but the trade off is that you can now override templates and won't loose your changes if you update twentytwelve (just the symlink).

Comment: Thanks Steven. I am confused, the Events Manager documentation states that: "It is now possible to simply insert specific files into your theme which will override certain aspects of Events Manager." More info here: http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/using-template-files/ ... so am i doing anything wrong? i am really confused ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your file path:

plugins/events-manager/templates/forms/event/bookings.php

should be

plugins/events-manager/forms/event/bookings.php

If you have issues with EM we monitor the free forums here (I stumbled on this by coincidence) - https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/events-manager

also @StevenLeimberg, thank for chipping in! we do support child themes it was just wrong directory structure.

Comment: Thanks Marcus! I will try this out.